# Promise {status: "pending"}

Tags: javascript, promises

```
buscarUsuario.onclick = function() {
            var usuario = document.getElementById("usuario").value;
            var resultado = buscaUsuario(usuario);
            console.log(resultado);
          }

const buscaUsuario = async(usuario) => {
          var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
          let url = 'http://192.168.1.144/status?usuario=' + usuario;
              http.onreadystatechange = () => {
                  if (http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
                      var data = http.responseText;
                  }else {
                    var data = "Error ao buscar, tente novamente";
                  }
                  return data;
              }
              await http.open("GET", url, true);
              await http.send();
        }
```

Como faço para que no código acima o console.log retorne o resultado da func buscaUsuario, que seria o respondeText da pagina que envio o argumento? o resultado do console log é:

> Promise {status: "pending"}

Vi que tem algo a ver com .then ou .catch mas eu nunca usei isso e não entendi como implementar no código.

Comment: Não manjo muito disso, mas não deveria ser `var resultado = await buscaUsuario(usuario);`?

Comment: Foi o que o Hiago disse, eu coloquei desta forma porém retorna undefined, não sei o motivo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Há dois erros em seu código:

- Você não está "esperando" o resultado da *promise*;
- Você está retornando o resultado na função `onreadystatechange`, sendo que o retorno deveria ser na função `buscaUsuario`

Uma forma de resolve isso, é usar a classe *Promise*. Segue exemplo abaixo.

```js
const buscarUsuario = document.querySelector('button')

/**
 * Nesta função, é obrigatório utilizar o operador `async`
 * Ele servirá para que possamos utilizar um outro operador
 * o `await`, que serve para indicar ao JS que queremos esperar
 * o resultado de uma função antes de ele prosseguir no código.
 *
 * Caso não façamos isso, o `console.log` será chamado antes
 * do resultado, já que a função `buscaUsuário` é assincrona
 */
buscarUsuario.onclick = async function() {
  var usuario = document.getElementById("usuario").value;
  var resultado = await buscaUsuario(usuario);
  console.log(resultado);
}

const buscaUsuario = async(usuario) => {
  /**
   * Retorna uma Promise
   * @params {Function} resolve Essa função será chamada quando ocorrer um sucesso na chamada da API
   * @params {Function} reject Essa função será chamada quando ocorrer uma falha na requisição
   */
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    let url = `https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random?usuario=${usuario}`;
    http.onreadystatechange = () => {
      if (http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
        resolve(http.responseText)
      } else if (http.readyState == 4 && http.status >= 400) {
        reject('Falha')
      }
    }
    http.open("GET", url, true);
    http.send();
  })
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="usuario" />
<button>Dogs</button>
```

Comment: Funcionou como esperado, entendi os erros cometidos, vou estudar um pouco mais sobre este assunto, obrigado Valdeir!

Answer (score 1):

Existem duas maneiras, ou você implementa a Promise ou então modifica sua function para utilizar async/await.

> Exemplo A:

```
buscarUsuario.onclick = async function() {
    var usuario = document.getElementById("usuario").value;
    var resultado = await buscaUsuario(usuario);
    console.log(resultado);
}

const buscaUsuario = function(usuario) {
   return new Promise ((res, rej) => {
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    let url = 'http://192.168.1.144/status?usuario=' + usuario;
        http.onreadystatechange = () => {
            if (http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
                var data = http.responseText;
            }else {
            var data = "Error ao buscar, tente novamente";
            }
            res(data);
        }
        http.open("GET", url, true);
        http.send();
  });
}
```

> Exemplo B:

```
buscarUsuario.onclick = function() {
    var usuario = document.getElementById("usuario").value;
    buscaUsuario(usuario).then(resultado => {
        console.log(resultado);
    });
}

const buscaUsuario = function(usuario) {
 return new Promise((res,rej)=> {
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    let url = 'http://192.168.1.144/status?usuario=' + usuario;
        http.onreadystatechange = () => {
            if (http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
                var data = http.responseText;
            }else {
            var data = "Error ao buscar, tente novamente";
            }
            res(data);
        }
        http.open("GET", url, true);
        http.send();
   });
}
```

Comment: Hiago, eu fiz das duas formas e ambas o console.log retornam: undefined, alguma sugestão? dentro da função buscaUsuario a variável data está com as informações que eu quero normalmente.

Comment: Entendi Vitor, vou atualizar a resposta.

Comment: Vitor, eu editei a resposta.