# Como pegar o retorno do post no meu scope angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Minha variável `scope.id_propertie` retorna *undefined*. lgum meio de pegar ela fora?

```
$http.post("consults/properties.php", {
  'action': 'list_properties'
}).then(function(response) {
  let data = response;
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    $scope.id_propertie = data[i].id_propertie;
  }
});

console.log($scope.id_propertie);
```

Comment: A lógica é a mesma: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/413864/99718

Comment: Não entendi sua resposta poderia ne da um exemplo com o codigo de cima?

Answer (score 1):

O angular retorna os dados em `response.data` e não em `response`.

Dica: depura a saída do `response`para ver o que está saindo, se é um objeto diferente do esperado, é muito comum perceber o erro depurando ou simplesmente escrevendo no `console.log()`.

Neste caso você deveria ajustar esta linha: `data = response;` para `let data = response.data;`, ou melhor `const data = response.data;`.